# Rails] Turning on CSS Class Active with current_page Method

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, current-page

In my view, I have:

`<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(:controller => 'posts') %>"><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>`

The problem is, when I move away from /posts/ path, the class is turned off again. For example, when I go to /posts/1, the link class is not active anymore. I thought it would still be active because the controller stays the same. How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'posts' %>
```

so try to debug what's the value of

```
params[:controller]
```

when you go to **/posts/1** to see why class "active" doesn't appear.

It could be that the class "active" is there but its not showing for a css issue? Check the source code on the browser on */posts/1** to see if the code is working or not

Comment: params[:controller] was consistently 'posts', but class active was not turned on when I used current_page? method. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="<%=params[:controller] == 'posts' ?  'active' : '') %>">
    <a href="/posts">Posts</a>
 </li>
```

The above will work for sure.